# asp.net pagemethods without aspx file extensions

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am calling web methods from javascript in an asp.net web application (c#)(Visual Studio 2013).
I could not work out why it was working on the first page but not any subsequent pages.

This is the first web application I have started (previously made websites). I was happy to notice you no longer needed to type the aspx extension which made for much cleaner urls.

It was just by chance I noticed the web methods were working if the extension was in the url (such as default.aspx), but not if not (default)

What is the best way around this. I am calling the webmethod from Javascript like this

```
 PageMethods.Test('Hello',OnSuccess, OnFailure);
```

Thank you

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21105220/795683

Comment: This is a known problem with Routes for WebForms. The PageMethods actually end up requesting `{resource}/{method}` instead of `{page.aspx}/{method}` because of routing rules. Either disable routing or use `set_path` to hard-code the url. See [this answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8147357/1355315) of which this is a possible dupe.