# AutoCompleteExtender Returns HTML Instead of JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

UPDATE 3:

Code behind for the GetGrowers call:

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace AmericanApple
{
public partial class ReceivingStation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bcDataTextBox.Focus();

    }


    [ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetGrowers(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        string[] growers = { "American Apple", "Lewis", "Grice" };
        return growers;
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I think I've identified the problem. When viewing the "Network" tab in Chrome developer tools, I can see the call to GetGrowers, and in the request headers, it's asking for `application/json` format, but in the response header, it returns `text/html`. So all those characters in the dropdown is actually the entire page in html.

In the working example I have, the response header for the Auto CE call is `application/json`. So for whatever reason, my project's response for this is not in the right format. I have checked the web.config file and don't see any differences between my working example and the project I'm working on.

[image]

UPDATE:

Image of what's happening in Chrome:

[image: AutoCompleteExtender in Chrome]

ORIGINAL:

I cannot get my AutoCompleteExtender to work. In Chrome and FireFox my auto complete results are a bunch of (random?) characters. In Internet Explorer only, when I click in the TextBox the page freezes and my Visual Studio output looks like this:

> Exception was thrown at line 39, column 3 in eval code
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 's' is undefined
>   Exception was thrown at line 37, column 3 in eval code
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'r' is undefined
>   Exception was thrown at line 31, column 3 in eval code
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'e' is undefined

...and keeps going like that indefinitely.

I have the latest AjaxControlToolkit installed: 17.1.1.
I'm using VS Pro 2015 version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3.
.NET Framework version 4.7.02046

In my Site.Master page I'm declaring

`<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>`

at the top and my script manager in the body:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

On the page running the AutoCompleteExtender:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteGrower" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtGrower"
    MinimumPrefixLength="0" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="true" UseContextKey="false"
    ServiceMethod="GetGrowers" CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_List" CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_ListItem"
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_HighlightedListItem" FirstRowSelected="true">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

My TextBox:

```
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtGrower" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoCompleteType="None"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
```

I have not found an AutoCompleteExtender question on SO with this same error. What am I missing here? The error is occurring before my ServiceMethod can return, I know that much.

Comment: It's hard to find the location of the error. Can you please add [StaticResources NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources) to your project, so that scripts were not minified?

Comment: I just tried installing v17.1.1 and the previous version, both times VS freezes with (Not Responding). I haven't had issues installing any other NuGet packages.

Comment: Made an update to the original post.

Comment: @MikhailTymchukDX is there another way to install StaticResources?

Comment: You can try to add your project into [the AJAX Control Toolkit solution](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit) and debug it locally.

Comment: I've updated my question: the response header from the call to "GetGrowers" from the AutoCompleteExtender is returning `text/html` instead of the expected `application/json` format. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the service method is not called. Can you confirm it is being called using direct request, like from browser or CURL?

Comment: The service method "GetGrowers" is being called, according to Fiddler and the Network tab of Chrome developer tools. It's called with status 200. Content-type is incorrect though. I've attached an image in my question.

Comment: Would you please show the page code-behind? `GetGrowers` signature, specifically.

Comment: I've added the full code behind in the original post, but here's the signature: `public static string[] GetGrowers(string prefixText, int count)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure my signature is correct, as I've seen that has been an issue for others and asked on SO before. My issue seems unique, which might be why so few have commented on it.

Comment: What version of IIS do you use? This question may be related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156529/ajax-returning-html-of-the-page-instead-of-results

Comment: @MikhailTymchukDX I just tried adding that line of code into my Web.config file `<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>` and it did not work. I'm running IIS version 10.0.

Comment: I also managed to install StaticResources and still no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the solution that worked was to add the method to a web service file (asmx.cs).

So the class declaration looks like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AmericanAppleServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
```

And the method declaration:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetGrowers(string prefixText, int count)
{
```

Using this method I also have to have the Service path declared in my AutoCompleteExtender in my .aspx page:

`ServicePath="AmericanAppleServices.asmx"`

I still do not know why the other way did not work, but this will do for now. @MikhailTymchukDX thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes, this is known workaround, but I thought you knew it. Don't forget to accept your own answer!

Comment: I had actually tried this before, but there must have been some errors in how I was declaring the class and the web method, as I was following a general example from somewhere online.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a problem with ASP.NET routing:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8147357/644496

Unfortunately, AJAX Control Toolkit can not detect if routing enabled or not.

The easiest way to workaround this is to specify page with `.aspx` extension as a `ServicePath`:

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender
        ID="AutoCompleteGrower"
        runat="server"
        TargetControlID="txtGrower"
        MinimumPrefixLength="1"
        CompletionInterval="100"
        EnableCaching="true"
        UseContextKey="false"
        ServicePath="ReceivingStation.aspx"
        ServiceMethod="GetGrowers"
        FirstRowSelected="true">
```

Comment: I've tried `ServicePath="ReceivingStation.aspx"` which gives a 401 error. And `ServicePath="ReceivingStation"` works the same as it does without adding a ServicePath (it still responds with text/html and the dropdown is the entire page in html).

Comment: I have a feeling my issue has something to do with my Ajax Control Toolkit installation or some Visual Studio/Build/Web Config settings. I was just troubleshooting another issue, where Modal Popup Extender would work locally, but not when published to my IIS server. In my developer tools I saw that ModalPopup.js and many other ACT scripts were getting 404s. I looked in my "Published" projects folder, and the AjaxControlToolkit folder with all the scripts wasn't there! It was just left out during publishing! I added it manually and now the modal popup works!

Comment: That's really strange. I suspect there something wrong with your deployment. How do you deploy your site (XCOPY, Web publish, etc.)?

Comment: I use "Build" -> "Publish" -> "Profile": Custom, "Connection": File System, "Settings": Release (no 'File Publish Options' selected). I copy the folder it creates to my IIS web sites location and configure its port. The AutoCompleteExtender does not even work when I run the site from VS, where as the Modal Popup did.

Comment: Can you share your project? It looks like deployment is correct.